# Using composition in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, composition

I want to make a request and cache it, in a functional style.

```js
const req = (uri) => 
    (console.log(`requesting: ${uri}`), Promise.resolve({ status: 200 }));

const cache = (fn) => (...args) => 
    fn(...args).then((result) => { console.log('caching:', result) });

const cachedReq = cache(req);

cachedReq('example.com/foo');
```

Two questions:

1. Is this code idiomatic?
2. How can I supply logic to generate the cache key from the result, while maintaining separation of concerns? For example, I might use `req` to retrieve different kinds of resource which need different logic to generate the key to be used in the cache. How should I supply this key-generation logic to the `cache` function?

**Edit:** 
In reality, the URI should be the key (thanks to @epascarello). I chose a poor example. But I'd like to ask about the more general case, where logic needs to be supplied "down composition", while maintaining decent separation of concerns.

Comment: Use the uri as the key?

Comment: install https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-hash
then use var key= hash(args)

Comment: Your `cache` function doesn't actually cache anything. Can you please provide your real code?

Comment: Caching requires mutable state, which needs special treatment in functional programming anyway, so there's nothing that is "idiomatic functional style" here

Comment: This is a contrived example. There is no real code unfortunately. Assume that the cache step calls out to a Redis instance using `set`.

Comment: Lazy evaluation allows for infinite data structures with inherent caching behavior. More [details](https://www.quora.com/What-are-common-idioms-for-caching-and-memoization-in-pure-functional-languages-such-as-Haskell).

Comment: "*Is this code idiomatic?*" - if you refer to the `const cachedReq = cache(req);

cachedReq('example.com/foo');` part and not to the implementation, yes this idea is totally fine. "*How should I supply this key-generation logic to the cache function?*" - as a second (possibly optional) parameter to `cache(…)`.

Comment: Thank you. The part `const cache = (fn) => (...args) => fn(...args)...`. Is this idiomatic too? ie the construction of the function to work with the composition. Finally, about "functional style" should I use a different term? Possibly "expression-oriented style." I am not implying I am using true functional programming here, but I am making a distinction between C-style statement-oriented code.

Answer (score 0):

You almost close to achieve your goal, you are in the right direction, with composition concept. maybe this code can help you to make your goal come true.

Let's simulate your req function like so:

```
var req = (uri) => {
    console.log("inside req", uri);
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve({ status: 200 });
        }, 3000);
    });
}
```

then you have the cacheFunc version as:

```
var withCache = (promiseFunc) => {
    const cache = {};
    return (...args) => {
        // suppose first param is uri
        var uri = args[0];
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            if (cache.hasOwnProperty(uri)) {
                return resolve(cache[uri]);
            }
            promiseFunc(...args).then((data) => {
              cache[uri] = data;
              resolve(data);
            }).catch(reject);
        });
    }
}
```

as you can see, you need to create and `cache` object into the first function, so this is a a little similar to [Currying in JS](https://wsvincent.com/javascript-currying/), so you need to wrap your req (that is a promise) wrapped into another promise from the cache version, so before execute the req function, you need to verify if some response exists into cache with the same uri key, if it is, so resolve inmmediatly the promise, else execute the req function, once you receive the response cache the response and resolve the cache promise version.

So you can use it like so:

```
var cacheReq = withCache(req);
cacheReq('https://anywhere.com').then(console.log.bind(null, 'response')).catch(console.log.bind(null, 'error response'));
```

you will notice that in the first time you promise wait until 3 seconds to resolve the req, in the second call the promise will resolve the promise ASAP because of cache, if you try with another uri it will wait 3 seconds again and will cache the response to use it the next time.

Hope it can help you.

Comment: Thank you. My question is really about how to pass functionality along a composition "chain". Maybe the only answer is: send it in the original argument.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of a Map and the [Request constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Requesthttps://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request):

```
// I'll be using ramda for object equality, but any
// deepEquals checker should work.
const R = window.R;

const genRequest = ((cache, eqComparator) => {
  return (url, fetchOpts={}) => {
    const key = {url, fetchOpts};
    const alreadyHave = [...cache.keys].find(x => eqComparator(x, key));
    if (alreadyHave) return cache.get(alreadyHave);
    const req = new Request(url, fetchOpts);
    cache.set(key, req);
    return req;
  };
})(new Map(), R.equals);

const req = genRequest('http://www.google.com');
fetch(req)
  .then(...)
  .catch(...);
```

Some nice properties fall out of this:

1. Each request is constructed only once but can be repeatedly `fetch`ed.
2. No side-effects until you fetch: creating the request and fetching it are separate.
3. ...thus, concerns are about as separated as they can be.
4. You could re-jigger parameter application to easily support custom equality comparisons using the same cache.
5. You can use the same strategy to cache the *results* of a fetch, separately from caching the requests.